# A-Frame: I'm unable to move using bluetooth remote in Chrome and Firefox for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, aframe, webvr

I'm unable to move using bluetooth remote in Chrome and Firefox for Android

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-environment-component/dist/aframe-environment-component.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v4.1.3/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <a-camera look-controls universal-controls>
          <a-cursor></a-cursor>
      </a-camera>

      <a-scene>
          <a-box color="red" rotation="0 45 45" scale="2 2 2" position="0 3 -5"></a-box>
          <a-entity environment="preset: forest; dressingAmount: 500"></a-entity>
      </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

But movement is working in non-VR mode (i.e. before pressing the glasses icon) in Chrome Beta, Dev and Canary

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

What gamepad? Does it show in the [gamepad tester](http://html5gamepad.com)? If not the gamepad is unfortunately not supported by the browser. If it does:

`movement-controls` has replaced `universal-controls` and you have to create a [camera rig](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/controls/README.md):

```
<a-entity id="rig"
      movement-controls>
<a-entity camera
        position="0 1.6 0"
        look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

If still does not work you have to make sure there’s a valid mapping of buttons to actions for your controller. More precisely look at the [gamepad-controls](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/controls/gamepad-controls.js) component.